# Selenium WebDriver- Chrome TimeOut?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to solve this issue, but I've had no luck in the past 3 hours. All I need now is using Selenium to open website in Chrome, but it just doesn't work. I tried using GeckoDriver, too, but it just throws a different kind of exception. All software involved are up-to-date. I even tried disabling my WiFi and using cellular data (I thought the connection was blocked by the firewall), but it doesn't work, either. If someone can help me I will be really appreciated! I have seen some similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of the answers work.

Here's my code:

```
package bot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Terminator {
    public static void main(String[] aaaa)  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/myName/Documents/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

And this is the runtime exception thrown:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2) on port 22038
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
>   System info: host: 'myName-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14b0:2df0:4281:99d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.2', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>       at bot.Terminator.main(Terminator.java:10)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:22038/status] to be available after 20005 ms
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>       ... 10 more

Comment: "All software involved are up-to-date" is not good enough. What are the actual version numbers for Selenium, Chrome, and ChromeDriver?

Comment: @Navarasu My question was asked on Jan.19.   That question was asked yesterday

Comment: Hmm Yes I am aware. I just started my account a week back and anwsering recent quesion. I found this related to it in suggection. As it is earlier, I have added it as comment here to reach the answer to you. @SiKing in the comment asked to flag this question. I didn't understand how to handle this? :(

Comment: @Navarasu Please see this answer on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/3124333 Flagging this as a duplicate is fine.

Comment: @Navarasu It’s ok. I don’t think it really matters that much 

Answer (score 0):

It may be either the Chrome Driver does not started or `localhost` hostname is not accesible.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821461/selenium-chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waitin/52824533#52824533) answer for debugging steps.

Comment: Please do not answer with link to another answer. If you feel this question is a duplicate, flag it as such.

Comment: Is it is possible flag old post?